# How do I match a word that starts with "I" but isn't the word "Integer"?

Tags: regex, string

How do I write a regular expression that will match all words starting with `I` except the word `Integer`?

Example:

```
  t1: Integer;
  t2: Interface;
  t3: IXml;
```

The result should be `Interface` and `IXml`.

Comment: Should it match a single 'I' or no?

Comment: Whatever, there are plenty of trivial questions on here, and this one is slightly tricky since you have to look ahead and then "re-consume" the same letters you looked at.

Comment: @back2dos - besides being rude and beating the purpose of this site, the one answer that was posted clearly shows that although not difficult, the solution as trivial as you claim.

Comment: @Pedro: which language are you using?

Comment: @mquander, @adamk: What I was trying to say is, it is not appropriate to use regex for such trivial things. I think, regexes obfuscate code, especially the ones, you don't understand. The purpose of SO is not to write code for those, who're not capable to write it themselves, but to help them, help themselves. IMHO answering this question just helps pedro to shoot himself into his foot. Maybe my tone was a little harsh, but I'm a little nerved by people, who don't seem to understand the fact, that 1. in programming, there is a certain hierarchy to things, 2. no tool is right for all purposes.

Comment: I'm using Delphi, but I need this to find all declarations of Interfaces in the source code. I use this tool: http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
I(?!nteger\b)\w+
```

Comment: … although Pedro, unfortunately, did not specify which flavor of regex he has. Not all regex libraries support negative lookahead.

Comment: You should remove the \w because it doesn't match de semicolumn ; given in examples.

Comment: @M42: the semicolon was not meant to be matched.

Comment: @Chris: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html any modern language supports negative look-ahead. Besides, it's not the reason to devalue my answer, and rather a reason to ask OP for clarifications.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I didn't downvote your answer, I had in fact upvoted it.

Comment: @Christopher: I never said you did. Thanks for the upvote, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t use a look-ahead assertion as SilentGhost suggested, you can express the same using basic regular expression syntax:

```
I(\b|[A-Za-mo-z][A-Za-z]*|n(\b|[A-Za-su-z][A-Za-z]*|t(\b|[A-Za-df-z][A-Za-z]*|e(\b|[A-Za-fh-z][A-Za-z]*|g(\b|[A-Za-df-z][A-Za-z]*|e(\b|[A-Za-qs-z][A-Za-z]*|r[A-Za-z]+))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
I(?!nteger).*
```